# My javascript breaks when I split a class into two classes

Tags: javascript, html, css, drag-and-drop

I'm currently making a Drag-and-Drop javascript engine. I want to make one class (`.drag`) the bare-minimum the element must have to be "drag-able". Currently my `.drag` class in css has some extra stuff in it and I want to split it into two classes. However, when I split the class, the object I wish to drag is no longer "drag-able".

Currently:

```
.drag {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    cursor:move;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

And I would like to have two classes:

```
.drag {
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

.square {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    cursor:move;
}
```

HTML changes from:

```
<p class="drag">Thing One</p>
<p class="drag">Thing Two</p>
```

To:

```
<p class="drag square">Thing One</p>
<p class="drag square">Thing Two</p>
```

And here is the javascript:

```
// JavaScript Document

var posX;
var posY;
var element;
var currentPos;

document.addEventListener("mousedown", drag, false);

function drag(event) {
    if(event.target.className == "drag") {
        element = event.target;
        element.style.zIndex="100";
        currentPos = findPos(element);
        posX = event.clientX -currentPos.x; //-parseInt(element.offsetLeft);
        posY = event.clientY -currentPos.y; //-parseInt(element.offsetTop);
        document.addEventListener("mousemove", move, false);
    }
}

function move(event) {

    if (typeof(element.mouseup) == "undefined")
        document.addEventListener("mouseup", drop, false);
    //Prevents redundantly adding the same event handler repeatedly

    element.style.left = event.clientX - posX + "px";
    element.style.top = event.clientY - posY + "px";
}

function drop() {
    element.style.zIndex="1";
    document.removeEventListener("mousemove", move, false);
    document.removeEventListener("mouseup", drop, false);
    //alert("DEBUG_DROP");
}    

function findPos(obj) { // Donated by `lwburk` on StackOverflow
    var curleft = curtop = 0;
    if (obj.offsetParent) {
        do {
            curleft += obj.offsetLeft;
            curtop += obj.offsetTop;
        } while (obj = obj.offsetParent);
        return { x: curleft, y: curtop };
    }
}
```

Why won't the elements drag when I split the class? How do I fix it?

Thank you so much for reading and helping! I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: *wonders why you would want to reinvent this wheel*. [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/)

Comment: This is my third day of Javascript. I want to learn the language before I start using libraries for shortcuts!

Comment: Fair enough. The first time I dug into JavaScript I too wrote the exact same functionality as you are working on here. :]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your conditional has `event.target.className == "drag"` but this is no longer true as now it `== "drag square"`.  What you want is something like:

`event.target.className.search(/\bdrag\b/) > -1`

for your conditional.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thank you. Can I do (use bitwise operators) if(~event.target.className.search(/drag/)) in javascript?

Comment: That shorthand should work just fine, though is less readable and saves only a couple characters.

Comment: `if (/\bdrag\b/.test(event.target.className))` seems more straightforward to me.

Comment: @gilly do you know which one is more efficient?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the line `if(event.target.className == "drag") {` will pull back "drag square" now - you should split the className on space and check to see if any of the classes are "drag".

Answer (score 0):

In your drag function you say:

```
event.target.className == "drag"
```

Could the issue be that once you have multiple classes on the element that the className no longer equals "drag" but is now the superset of classes "drag square".  You could try doing a search on the className to find if one of the classes is "drag" instead of only drag.